# Can $X \ne \{0\} \implies X^*\ne\{0\}$ be proved without Hahn-Banach theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

We know that if $X \ne \{0\}$ is a NLS then $X^*\ne\{0\}$ ; is there any way to prove it without using Hahn-Banach theorem ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Probably this question (and answer) already exist here.  My favorite example is the quotient Banach space
$$
X = l^\infty/c_0
$$
Of course $X \ne 0$.  But it is consistent with ZF that $X^* = 0$.  So you need **some** principle beyond ZF for your assertion.  Of course, Hahn-Banach is taylor made to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the counterexample that you are searching (not normable, only metrizable): the $\ell^p$ spaces for $0<p<1$ (non-locally convex) don't have the Hahn-Banach property but ($\ell^p)'\ne \{0\}$. See [On the Hahn-Banach Theorem](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/a/o/58.tex) by Lawrence Narici.

EDIT: quote from the some source:

> A topological vector space X has a nontrivial dual if and only if there is a proper convex neighborhood of 0.

In the case of normed spaces, this condition is obviously true and the answer to your question is affirmative.